# how to show and hide element inside a directive depending on its attributes with angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm pretty new to angular.

I created a directive which calls a featured itens templateUrl that will be reused in multiple parts of the page.. this partial sometimes display a "view all itens"button, and sometimes it doesn't show it, I want to pass it through the directive, something like that:

`<featured-itens show-btn='true'></featured-itens>`

and inside the partial, something like that

```
<div class='feat'>
    <ul>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="btn" ng-show='showBtn === true' />
 </div>
```

js

```
app.directive("featured", function() {
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    templateUrl: "/partials/featured.html",
  };
});
```

How could I achieve this result?

Comment: Where is your directive?

Comment: Your directive needs to have a javascript code

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to do =P..for now I only have this
    app.directive("featured", function() {
      return {
        restrict:"E",
        templateUrl: "/partials/featured.html",
      };
    });

Comment: There is a pretty nice [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) It has lots of examples.

Comment: I read this documentation, but I couldn't manage to do that =/

Comment: you can isolate scope for reusability

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<featured show-btn="true"></featured>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive("featured", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/partials/featured.html",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            showBtn: '=?'
        }
    };
});
```

**Template**

```
<div class='feat'>
    <ul>
        <li>.gdsfg..</li>
        <li>..sdfg.</li>
        <li>..fdgdf.</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="btn" ng-show='showBtn === true'> Button </a>
</div>
```